# SaveChanges() on entity not updating records, no exception thrown

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

code as below:

```
Mailinglists_Details _addMail_Details = new Mailinglists_Details();
_addMail_Details.listname = mailingData[counter].listname;
_addMail_Details.usage = mailingData[counter].usage;
_addMail_Details.responsible = mailingData[counter].responsible;

db.AddToMailinglists_Details(_addMail_Details);
db.SaveChanges();
```

as you might see from the code yourself: `Entities db = new Entities()`

`AddToMailinglists_Details(obj)` is a shortcut for `AddObject("Mailinglists_Details", obj)`
for clarification:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
public void AddToMailinglists_Details(Mailinglists_Details mailinglists_Details)
{
this.AddObject("Mailinglists_Details", mailinglists_Details);
}
```

the strange thing now is, when creating some dummy records using the exactly same syntax works. The only difference to the dummy records is, that the entity is declared explicitly and not in a using statement, could that cause the problem? (mind that the comparison inside the same using assembly worked!!)

EDIT: For further clarification, the Table i am accessing is fully independent, here you got some code on how the dummy data are generated:

```
    Mailinglists_Details _addDetails_Mail = new Mailinglists_Details();
    _addDetails_Mail.listname = "apprentices@domain.com";
    _addDetails_Mail.usage = "Contact all apprentices @enterprise";
    _addDetails_Mail.responsible = "default responsible: some ppl";

    ent_mail.AddToMailinglists_Details(_addDetails_Mail);
    ent_mail.SaveChanges();
```

i have also tried `mailingData[counter].listname.ToString();`

EDIT2: mailingData is `List<customClass>`, Custom Class extends 4 properties: listname(string), usage(string), responsible(string), recipients(string[])

Comment: please add the using statement (does it encompass the call to savechanges?)

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, but i can tell you that SaveChanges() is a method to Entities, that is supposed to update the changes from the entity to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `db.MalingLists.Add(_addMail_Details);` instead of the call to `db.AddToMailinglists_Details` - it's possible there's a problem in the method you've created.

Comment: sorry to tell you, but i use the same method to generate the dummy-records and it works perfectly fine. also the method `db.MailingLists_Details.Add()` does not exist...

Answer (score 0):

Incase Mailinglists_Details is dependent to another entity you need to fill it using its navigation property for ex: considering you have MailingList 1->* MailingListDetails relation. In this case you have to put  `MailingListDetails.MailingList = mailingListObject;`

Comment: this is not the case, Mailinglists_Details is independant

Comment: I don't see why this doesn't work, Could you please provide full code portion? (including the context initiation)

Comment: i took away context initiation to declare `Entities db = new Entities()`, which made a different piece of code work again.